# CPU usage while gaming

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu-usage

If my CPU usage is 100% all the time wile gaming but the temp stay average (around 60°C - 70°C), will it destroy my CPU? My laptop use Athlon silver processor with built in graphic. For now, I only play for around 2 hours and let the laptop sleep since I'm afraid that going 100% all the time will destroy my CPU. Can someone help with my problem, please?

Also by upgrading RAM, will it reduce CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

From the temperature given, there should be no problem. A CPU does not wear out from overuse, but *can* be destroyed from overheating. If it's running at 70°C, and the maximum operating temperature [is listed as 95°C](https://askgeek.io/en/cpus/AMD/Athlon-Silver-3050U) for the AMD Athlon Silver 3050U, for example, it appears to be safe.

As for more RAM, it *might* help game-play, depending on how much RAM is in there now, or not, but it likely will do nothing for CPU usage or temp.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wont destroy your CPU - at least not in a timeframe that makes any real-world difference.

Its worth noting that non-ancient CPUs have built in thermal throttling built in- ie the cpu will slow itself down if it gets to hot - so worst case, gaming may be affected but not the CPU.

Upgrading your RAM may actually cause your CPU to work marginally more as it can get instructions to process faster - ie the bottleneck between RAM and CPU decreases, so the CPU spends less time in a wait state.

Not something you asked, but related. If you leave your computer processing at full load all the time it will use noticeably more power - this extra power use would be more of a financial concern then the extra wear and tear on the CPU.